# how to ask XSD.exe to generate proper class for me, so that i can create a fine XML

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xsd, xsd.exe

I have created an XSD file from Visual Studio 2010,

Then I use `xsd /c mydemo.xsd` to generate class for me, so that I can create a XML file at runtime.

However, when I use that class, fill in some values, and serialize the object, the XML file does  not look nice to me.

Here is my XSD file [Click here to see](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/284185/demo.xsd)

What I expected the XML file to be is [Click here to see](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/284185/expected-output.xml)
(Generated from Visual Studio "Sample XML")

But when I try to serialize it, the XML file is like this [CLick here to see](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/284185/output.xml)

The format is totally different

e.g

Expecting:

```
<ColumnInfo> 
  <Column Type="Type1" DisplayValue="DisplayValue1" Key="Key1"/> 
  <Column Type="Type2" DisplayValue="DisplayValue2" Key="Key2"/> 
  <Column Type="Type3" DisplayValue="DisplayValue3" Key="Key3"/> 
</ColumnInfo>
```

but the generate result is like this:

```
<columnInfoField>
  <ColumnType>
    <displayValueField>Display value for key 1</displayValueField>
    <keyField>key1</keyField>
    <typeField>string</typeField>
  </ColumnType>
  <ColumnType>
    <displayValueField>Display value for key 2</displayValueField>
    <keyField>key2</keyField>
    <typeField>int</typeField>
  </ColumnType>
  <ColumnType>
    <displayValueField>Display value for key 3</displayValueField>
    <keyField>key3</keyField>
    <typeField>long</typeField>
  </ColumnType>
</columnInfoField>
```

And the code I implement to serialize the report is :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731073.aspx

```
DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Report));
using (XmlDictionaryWriter xdw = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateTextWriter(File.Create(@"C:\demo\schema\output.xml"), Encoding.UTF8))
{
  dcs.WriteObject(xdw, report);
}
```

Not sure why I cannot use "XmlSerializer", when I use it, it will complain about cannot cast array type something...

> Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
>   error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'ColumnValueType[]' to
>   'ColumnValueType'
>   error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'ColumnValueType' to
>   'ColumnValueType[]'

So, does anyone can give me some suggestion, how can i fix my XML format???

Comment: please don't put things like "[C#]" in your titles. Just leave them in the tags.

Comment: @John ok... thx , i will keep in mind

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug on xsd.exe - look at this blog-post:
http://satov.blogspot.com/2006/12/xsdexe-generated-classes-causing.html

Answer (score 0):

The data contract serializer has different rules that the XmlSerializer.  Why don't you try the XmlSerializer first and then see if the output is "correct".

Comment: do you mean use XmlSerializer to work on the "class" generate from XSD.exe?... they are not working with each other, XmlSerializer complain cannot case arry type to xml element